# Two boxes (11w, 4b - 8w, 5b), take a random box, then a random ball, probability that it was from first

Tags: probability

> We have 2 boxes, the first box contains 11 white balls and 4 black
>   balls and the second box contains 8 white balls and 5 black balls. We
>   randomly choose a box (50% probability for each), then we randomly
>   choose a ball. If the chosen ball is white, what's the probability
>   that it came from the first box?

I've seen some proofs and results calculated using Bayes' theorem but I don't see the meaning of doing this, I don't understand why the result wouldn't be 50%.

As long as we have a white ball, the probability to be from the first box is 50% first (to select the box) then 100% to pick the ball (as we cannot pick a black one as the case would be irrelevant for our hypothesis). And 0.5 * 1 is 0.5.

I understand that if you generate a population by the rules, and then you pick a white ball from it, the chance is higher that it came from the first box, but if you pick one and it must be white (like stated in hypothesis), why would that be influenced in any way by the existence of black balls?

Comment: Our sample space consists of all the ways a white ball could be selected.  Our favorable cases consist of those selections which result in the selection of a white ball from the first box.

Comment: Suppose one box had 19 white balls and 1 black, and the other had 1 white and 19 black. A white ball ends up being picked. Knowing that, would you still bet even money that the second box had been chosen (even though that 50/50 chance was originally true)?